# Track R Shiny app with Google Analytics

Tags: r, google-analytics, shiny

I would like to use track my R Shiny app using google analytics. I followed this article https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/google-analytics.html.

I have a google analytics account and have copied and pasted the provided script into a .js script as suggested.

Having tried a number of alternatives and now storing the .js file in a folder named www I am currently attempting to embed the script in my UI using:
`header=singleton(tags$head(tags$script(src= "./www/google_analytics.js")))`

In the google_analytics.js script I have pasted the google analytics script exactly as I copied:

`<!-- Global site tag (gtag.js) - Google Analytics -->`

`<script async src= https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=UA-mynumber-1 ></script>`

`<script>`

`window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];`

`function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}`

`gtag('js', new Date());`

`gtag('config', 'UA-mynumber-1');`

`</script>"`

I have had no activity on google analytics even though I have visited the shiny IO page regularly over the past week. What am I missing here please?

Comment: This answer worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46574477/google-analytics-for-shiny-dashboard-app